# How to set distance between bars in a horizontal bar diagram

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, counter, diagram

I want to plot a bar diagram from a python counter.

```
toplist = countersum.most_common(len(countersum))
topkeylist = list()
topvallist = list()
for i in range(len(toplist)):
    topkeylist.append(toplist[i][0])
    topvallist.append(toplist[i][1])
for i in range(len(toplist)):
    print(topkeylist[i],":" ,topvallist[i])

keylist = list()
for key in topkeylist:
    keylist.append(str(key))

plt.barh(keylist[:100], topvallist[:100], height = 0.3, align = 'center')
plt.xlabel('Occurence inside the dataset')
plt.ylabel('N-gram sample')
plt.show()
```

It gives me the following plot:

[image]

I would like to set the spaces between bars so they can even touch and also align the text to the bar - as in the text size would be the same as the width of the bar to read it better.

Answer (score 1):

you can adjust the width of the bars by using the width parameter here:

```
plt.barh(keylist[:100], topvallist[:100], height = 0.3, align = 'center', width=5).
```

Also, try reducing the font size on the y-axis so that the tick marks are clearer:

```
plt.yticks(fontsize=10).
```

If this does not work, you can increase the size of the figure using

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,18))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set what you want in a `dict` and use [`rcParams.update(params)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/customize_rc.html#customize-rc) like below:

*( because I can't run your code, send an example)*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
random.seed(123)

params = {'figure.figsize'  : (50, 40),
          'axes.labelsize'  : 30,
          'axes.titlesize'  : 30,
          'xtick.labelsize' : 20,
          'ytick.labelsize' : 20}
plt.rcParams.update(params)

plt.barh([random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(200)], 
         [random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(200)], 
         height = 0.5, align = 'center')
plt.xlabel('Occurence inside the dataset')
plt.ylabel('N-gram sample')
plt.yticks(range(110))

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]